# How to change / reconfig F2 key bringing up Gnome Menu

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, eclipse

Currently, in Ubuntu 18.04, pressing F2 brings up a "Gnome Menu" in the top left corner.

This is not Alt+F2 or Fn+F2. It's just straight F2.

But F2 is also a shortcut in Eclipse, which I use a lot. The Ubuntu F2 overrides the Eclipse F2, losing the Eclipse functionality.

Going into Keyboard Shortcut settings, I don't see anyway to reconfigure or change or disable the F2 key. I can see options for changing Alt+F2, but not straight F2.

What do I need to know about this?

---

UPDATE: Screenshot of Desktop.

I forget all the widgets I've installed over the past year. Pressing F2 pops up this menu, but I can't find a settings toggle for it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I cant reproduce this on my Ubuntu 18.04.. F2 is not doing anything.. Alt+F2 is is asking me to enter a command.. some thing different in your situation.. I think some other settings giving you F2=Gnome Menu.. can you attach a screen shot.. what is gnome menu? do you mean when you press super+a keys.. what shows.. is that?

Comment: did you set the windows key to F2 perhaps?

Comment: @PRATAP Screenshot added

Comment: @Rinzwind  The Windows key does this sort of zoom-out of all the different windows you have open.  The F2 key is the one I want to work in Eclipse, but which Ubuntu is using for its own purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you have *installed* `gnome-shell-extenion` [Gno-Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/608/gnomenu/).

This *menu* has the <kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut for *"Disable Menu button shortcut key"*.

To access the settings options for this extension, open `gnome-tweaks`. If it is not installed, install it by `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`. Go to the *Extensions* tab. Click on the *Settings* icon on Gno-menu.

[image]

You can tick/check this option to disable the <kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut for this function...

Note: While choosing this option to tick/ check... my system hanged, unresponsive. After several reboots, only this option is enabled...